# $watch collection change before item gets inserted to collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I use ui-select multiple, and I need to check the collection, before ng-model="collection" gets updated, to see if new value is already in it.
$watching collection doesn't help, because the item is already added and then $watch gets called..

on-select neither helped me, same case, collection gets updated before, and I can't check if currently clicked item is already in it before it gets pushed.

Anyway i could test it, before ng-model gets updated?

The purpose of that, is to check for duplicates and to not add them.

Comment: What is the purpose of checking this? how does the result of that check help you?

Comment: To check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you can do this:

```
$scope.$watch('myArray', removeDuplicates);
removeDuplicates($scope.myArray)

function removeDuplicates(array){
    ...
};
```